# Aron Eisenberg, who played Nog on ST:DS9, died today at age 50

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Aron Eisenberg, known to SFF fans for his recurring role as the Ferengi Nog in *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, died today at the age of 50. The cause of death has not been revealed.

I personally loved Nog's storyline when I discovered Deep Space Nine for the first time. Aron's portrayal of the character, as well as the way Nog evolved throughout the series, always amazed me. One scene that struck me deep was when Nog finally revealed to Sisko why he wanted to join the Academy so much, the emotion was very palpable.

https://intl.startrek.com/news/aron-eisenberg-obituary-star-trek

https://edition.cnn.com/2019/09/22/entertainment/aron-eisenberg-star-trek-actor-dies/index.html

Comment: His portrayal of a loyal son torn between making his own place in the universe against following traditional Ferengi culture ([ST-DS9 S03E14](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_of_Stone_(episode))) brings a tear to my eye every I watch the episode, You will be missed Aron. *Of my friend, I can only say this: of all the souls I have encountered in my travels, his was the most... human.*

Comment: His injury and subsequent recovery also make for some compelling episodes.

Comment: He also played a young Kazon-Ogla in early Voyager. For those who didn't know, he had been having kidney problems since he was young. 2 transplants later it looks like the illness finally caught up with him.

Comment: In lieu of a funeral canisters of his vacuum-desiccated remains will be placed up for auction.